# How to toggle selected features by clicking on them in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, javascript

This is my website for test: http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/ol_simple.html

This is my expected result:http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/test.html

I want to try this effect in OpenLayers.

If the feature is selected, I click again to unselect the feature. Additionally, clicking out should not unselect the feature.

I tried it whole day. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. In your JavaScript file `ol_simple.js` just change:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(GridshpLayer,{ multiple: true});
```

by:

```
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(GridshpLayer,{ clickout: false, toggle: true, multiple: true});
```

Comment: I tried some method. But, that is not working. So, I deleted them. Thanks for your help.